# I lost my private key

Tags: encryption

Sir I lost my private key and I have got a message to decrypt it’s asking me for my private key from past 10 days I am trying . But nothing worked . My only hopes is u sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond to ransom attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160582/how-to-respond-to-ransom-attack)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you lost your private key, it is over.

Unless you used some really short key length, (say 256 bit), a crypto-attack will take too long.